VSC - Oracle SQL Developer Extension - Immediately jumps into Terminal when typing
I have the extension "Oracle SQL Developer Extension" for VSC. But I have an annoying problem.
Whenever I write something, the Editor jumps into the Output window at the bottom and shows Problems. Although, those problems only exist because I currently write something and therefore have an incomplete SQL Code.
This is highly frustrating.
How do I fix this?

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the Auto save attribute to Off (which was delayed before)
After this change the focus stays at the editor!
